# Не получается использовать утилиту siege

Tags: ubuntu

при использовании утилиты siege сталкиваюсь с такими ошибками, не знаю в чем проблема. Сеть настроена, пингуется в обе стороны.
[image: Скриншот терминала]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Если верить https://www.joedog.org/siege-faq/, разделу - "How many concurrent users should I use", вы превышаете норму пользователей для вашего сайта. Копать думаю в этом направлении надо